# Custom toggle button with image in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am new in react-native and want to design toggle button with image

[image]

[image]

I am following this links but not getting expected result

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/switch.html

https://github.com/aminebenkeroum/toggle-switch-react-native

Can any one please help me how I can design this.

Comment: What have you tried? At least try something out first and go back here once you encounter some problem.

Comment: looks like you've designed it already ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/R52N0.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIH1w.png

Comment: This image is created by photoshop

Comment: Combine the CSS and animation magical tools together to achieve this effect

Comment: If you check library file(ToggleSwitch.js) of toggle-switch-react-native, you will what html code is used and how it is animated. I suggest you try to replace that HTML with your images and modify some animation code, you will get your output. 

You just need to give it a shot and get back if you are facing any problem!

Good luck!